# Determine the functional spaces that contain the following function

Tags: functional-analysis

Define:
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0;\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space x<-1\\
1-x^2;\space\space\space -1 \leq x \leq 1\\
0;\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space x>1\
\end{cases}
$$
Determine what functional spaces that $f$ belong to.

My work so far:
Be examining $f'(x)$, I know that $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ but $f \notin C^1(\mathbb{R})$

However, I am having trouble determining which space $L^p$ that $f$ belongs to. Also, I wonder if $f$ belongs to any Sobolev space $W^{k,p}$.

Comment: Continuous with compact support guarantees you that the integrals you typically need to consider exist

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Do you mean my function belongs to $L^1$, and thus belongs to $L^p$, $\forall p$?